# Hierarchical dropdown menu from array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, drop-down-menu

I have the following code which fetches fields from my database and places them into an html form's dropdown menu for Formats. In it's current form, I am fetching from my database 3 times, how the code works is explained in the comments of the code:

```
$getSolos = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM wp_terms p 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy t ON p.term_id = t.term_id
        WHERE t.taxonomy = 'format'
        AND t.parent = 0
        AND t.term_id NOT IN (SELECT parent FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'format' AND parent > 0)
        ORDER BY t.parent
        "));  // This fetches all rows that do not have children or parents.

$getParents = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM wp_terms p 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy t ON p.term_id = t.term_id
        WHERE t.taxonomy = 'format'
        AND t.parent = 0
        AND t.term_id IN (SELECT parent FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'format' AND parent > 0)
        "));    // This fetches all rows that have children

$getChildren = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM wp_terms p 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy t ON p.term_id = t.term_id
        WHERE t.taxonomy = 'format'
        AND t.parent > 0
        ORDER BY t.parent
        AND p.name
        "));    //This fetches all rows that ARE children

<select name="format">  //start the dropdown
    <option value="empty"></option>  //default field is empty
        <?php 
            foreach ($getSolos as $solo) {  //start loop through solos for output
                echo "<option value='".$solo->name."'>".$solo->name."</option>"; // output solos as options in the dropdown
            }
            foreach ($getParents as $parent) { //start loop through parents for output
                echo "<optgroup label='".$parent->name."'>"; // Spit out parent as an optgroup
                foreach ($getChildren as $child) { //Start loop through children for output
                    if ($child->parent == $parent->term_id) { // if child's parent value matches the ID of the parent
                        echo "<option value='".$child->name."'>    ".$child->name."</option>"; //Spit out the child as an option
                    }
                }
                echo "</optgroup>"; //close the optgroup
            }
        ?>
    </select> // end the dropdown
```

The output is as follows:

```
Entry Form
Twitter
Facebook
 - Entry Form
 - Page
```

The combined table from the database looks like this:

```
term_id       name           slug                 taxonomy     parent
1             Entry Form     entry-form           format       0
2             Page           page                 format       3
3             Facebook       facebook             format       0
4             Entry Form     facebook-entry-form  format       3
5             Twitter        twitter              format       0
```

There is a problem with this method however.

1) It is inefficient to access the database 3 times.

2) It is ineffective if a child also has a child. While the children of children do all go into $getChildren, the code will only spit out 1st level children and ignore the rest.

For demonstration purposes, if I have 6th row:

```
term_id       name          slug                  taxonomy     parent
6             Single        single                format       2
```

Then the code would do this:

```
Entry Form
Twitter
Facebook
 - Entry Form
 - Page
```

Notice that Single is completely ignored, ALTHOUGH it is contained inside the $getChildren array.

So how can this code be made better?

Comment: Can we have an example of database source? Feels like this is can be done with some sql finesse...

Comment: The example is already provided.

Comment: You gave one table, but used more in your examples... ***shrugs***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row 6 has a parent with the value 2. Though the row with term_id 2 has a parent with the value 3 and thus is not included in your parents object.

I would probably use a function to achieve this;

```
$getTerms = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
              SELECT * FROM wp_terms p 
              WHERE t.taxonomy = 'format'
              ORDER BY p.name ASC"));

$terms = array();              
foreach($getTerms as $key => $term){
  $terms[$term->parent][$term->term_id] = $term;
} 

function printTerms($terms, $parent = 0, $deep = 0){
  if(count($terms[$parent]) > 0){

    $indent = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $deep; $i++){
      $indent .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }

    foreach($terms[$parent] as $key => $term){

      if(count($terms[$term->term_id]) > 0){

        if($deep == 0){
          echo "<optgroup label='".$term->name."'></optgroup>";
        } else {
          echo "<option value='".$term->name."'>".$indent.$term->name."</option>";
        }

        printTerms($terms, $term->term_id, ($deep+1));

      } else {

        echo "<option value='".$term->name."'>".$indent.$term->name."</option>";

      }

    }
  }
}

?>    

<select name="format">
   <option value="empty"></option>
   <?php printTerms($terms); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hmm. It's a start but ideally the optgroup would only apply to a top level parent while sub-parents would be selectable.

Comment: In that case you could build in a check on parent = 0. When its not 0 you can simply output an option. ill update answer tomorrow, i'm on a phone ;)

Comment: I edited the printTerms() function. It now supports selectable sublevel-parents, optgroup doesnt support a selectable label so i used an indentation, to visualise the level hierarchy, depending on deepness.

Comment: Also worth mentioning; I used 1 query to retrieve the data we need. Let PHP do the work for you! :)

Comment: The code doesn't output any indentation at all. It prints out Facebook as an optgroup but it's children have no indents and neither do the children of those children.  I think the reason why is because it echoes "<optgroup label='".$term->name."'></optgroup>"; which closes the optgroup before anything can be inserted into it.

Comment: No that shouldn't be a problem since its only a label. I found the problem, it has to do with the padding that is given. Only FireFox supports this. So another solution would be to work with &nbsp; to visualise the indent. Answer update comming up.

Comment: This might be useful: http://blog.christopherschultz.net/index.php/2009/02/10/indenting-html-select-options/

Comment: I took a look at the URL you provided and here's the thing - despite the chart provided on the site, the only method that works in chrome is the em dashes. It seems NONE of the css styling (bold/italics) they are using works, not even the white-on-white method for em dashes. If using em dashes is necessary, then so be it, however this method is UGLY. This is turning into quite an aggravating problem!

Comment: That's because the selectbox is from the stone-age. Every OS/Browser is using it in its own way and provide nearly no styling options. If you want more freedom in design you should write/use a javascript plugin that provides the same functionality. Though you can still use the principal of the function i wrote for you. You can make lists for everything from 1 level deep to infinitely levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up your output to display like this to create headers in the select:

```
    <select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

This means you will need to somehow recognize what output should be a label and what should be an option.

Comment: I believe this to be possible but I am going to need help to make that happen. Please see my updated question with the new information.

Comment: You are going to need to get out of the foreach loop and get this infomation in a while loop. then you will just need to do conditional checks. EX: if($format->parent) do this ELSE do this

Answer (score 0):

Did not test it, but i would first create a hierachical array with all IDs:

```
$items = array();
$ids   = array();
foreach ($getFormats as $format) {
    $items[$format->term_id] = $format;
    if (isset($format->parent)) {
        $ids[$format->parent->term_id][] = $format->term_id;
    } else $ids[$format->term_id] = null;
}
```

Then it's easy to walk through this array and create the HTML code:

```
foreach ($ids as $id => $subIds) {
    if (!empty($subIds)) {
        echo '<optgroup label="' . $items[$id]->name . '">';
        foreach ($subIds as $subId) 
            echo '<option value="' . $items[$subId]->name . '">' . $items[$subId]->name . '</option>';
        echo '</optgroup>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="' . $items[$id]->name . '">' . $items[$id]->name . '</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it creates the dropdown, but everything is treated the same. The  optgroups don't seem to work.